# Has Many Through Association Extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to setup a has many through an association extension? I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :friendships do
    def accepted
      where status: "accepted"
    end
    def rejected
      where status: "rejected"
    end
  end

  has_many :friends, through: :friendships do
    def accepted
      # Something equivalent to the following using association extension:
      # where("friendships.status = 'accepted'")
    end
    def rejected
      # Something equivalent to the following using association extension:
      # where("friendships.status = 'rejected'")
    end
  end

end
```

How can I setup my friend association (through friendships) using the friendships association extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Arel expressions for the `where` relation, you can then unbind those methods and rebind them to the `friends` association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships do
    def accepted
      where(Friendship.arel_table[:status].eq('accepted'))
    end
    def rejected
      where(Friendship.arel_table[:status].eq('rejected'))
    end
  end

  has_many :friends, through: :friendships do
    def accepted
      proxy_association.owner.friendships.extensions.first.instance_method(:accepted).bind(self).call
    end
    def rejected
      proxy_association.owner.friendships.extensions.first.instance_method(:rejected).bind(self).call
    end
  end
end
```

With that code, the SQL will be generated properly, so this test passes:

```
def test_stuff
  tom = User.create! name: "tom"
  fred = Friend.create! name: "fred"
  jerry = Friend.create! name: "jerry"
  Friendship.create! user: tom, friend: fred, status: 'accepted'
  Friendship.create! user: tom, friend: jerry, status: 'rejected'
  tom.reload
  fred.reload
  assert_equal "fred", tom.friends.accepted.first.name
  assert_equal "jerry", tom.friends.rejected.first.name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing coming to my mind:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :accepted_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :conditions => ...
  has_many :accepted_friends, through => :accepted_friendhips, :source => :friend

end
```

Comment: I'd prefer to find a method that works with the association extensions if possible, and am aware that it can be done using this method. Thanks.